# Set different views as default for different groups in SharePoint 2013 library

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-views

In my SharePoint 2013 document Library, I have created a view called 'Certificates' and then using target audience I have assigned one group A the permission on this new view. And on the default 'All Documents' view I have assigned another group B the permission.

- If I login as a user from group B, I am able to see 'All Documents' view but not 'Certificates' as it has no permission.
- If I login as a user from group A, I cant see anything as the default view is 'All Documents' and if I manually type the url as http://server/forms/certificates.aspx they are able to see it as they have the permission.

So How can I set the default view for a group so that whenever the users from specific group open the library they should see only those views on which they have access.e.g. If users from group A login, the default view should be 'Certificates'.

I have used this blog : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/12e7a557-9a39-4107-8652-5e61df606c52/how-to-set-default-sharepoint-list-view-based-upon-user-group?forum=sharepointdevelopment and used codeplex plugin but its not working and its giving different errors which I am not willing to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved by these steps.

1. Edit the "All Documents" view page and add the same document library web part.
2. Edit the top web part, select "Certificates" view and set the target audience (group A).
3. Edit the last web part, select the "All Documents" view and set the target audience (group B)

Test using different logins from group A and B. This should display "Certificates" to group A and "All Documents" to group B.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a current user filter web part.

[Office instructions here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/connect-a-filter-web-part-to-a-list-view-web-part-on-a-classic-page-4f3f6c10-0a1b-479d-8b4d-c4f1bf49bb3f) and a [nice youtube video here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ret9lkuCtjY).

Comment: Chris, please provide instructions in your answer. Linking to other web pages is useless if these web pages get taken down or deleted in the future.